# ¿Cómo evitar que se elimine el párrafo completo al ejecutar esta función?

Tags: javascript

Como puedo evitar, que cuando yo le pase el segmento de un párrafo a la función ***hidden_text***, me remplace solo el segmento que quiero y no me elimine completo, que es lo que me esta haciendo ahora. Les dejo código para ver si me pueden ayudar:

```
    function panime (i = 0){

        $(ps[i]).text(function(){
            if(val != ''){
                a_str = $(this).text().trim().split(" ");
                len = a_str.length;
                var v = '';
                if(len > 5){
                    v = len / 5;
                    v = Math.round(v);
                }else{
                    v = 1
                }
                search = '';
                ini = 0
                //Conformamos la cadena a trabajar.
                for(c = 0; c < v; c++){
                    a_seg = '';
                    a_seg = a_str.splice(ini,5);
                    if(a_seg != ''){

                        hidden_text(a_seg,ps[i]);
                        search = '';
                        ini = ini + 5;                      
                    }
                }
                panime(i + 1);              
            }               
        });

}

function hidden_text(a_seg,tp,callback) {

        search = a_seg.toString().replace(/,/gi," ");
        search = search.replace(/&nbsp;/g,"");
        var regex = new RegExp(search,'gi');
            $(tp).html($(this).text().replace(regex,'<span style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 18px;">'+search+'</span>'));

    if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Contenido del HTML

```
    <div class="span10" style="text-align:justify; margin-left: 90px;" id="texto0"><p class="NormalText" style="text-align:justify">
    <u><span style="font-size:18.0pt">LEYES PARA EL OCÉANO</span></u><span style="font-size:18.0pt">*<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="NormalText" style="text-align:justify">
    <span style="font-size:18.0pt">&nbsp;</span></p>
<p class="NormalText" style="text-align:justify">
    <span style="font-size:18.0pt">En los últimos cincuenta años el derecho marítimo internacional se ha desarrollado con suma rapidez. No es de extrañar, dada la presión sin precedentes que sufren los océanos, sus recursos y el medio marino.<o:p></o:p></span></p>
<p class="NormalText" style="text-align:justify">
    <span style="font-size:18.0pt">&nbsp;</span><span style="font-size: 18pt;">La Convención de las Naciones Unidas sobre el Derecho del Mar, el tratado más importante jamás negociado en ese ámbito, es relativamente reciente. Entró en vigor el 16 de noviembre de 1994. Pero sus orígenes se remontan a comienzos de los años cincuenta, época en que se creó la Comisión de Derecho Internacional de las Naciones Unidas, encargada de desarrollar teniendo en cuenta la práctica de los Estados, el derecho internacional, gran parte del cual era necesario redactar.</span></p>
<p class="NormalText" style="text-align:justify">
    <span style="font-size:18.0pt">&nbsp;</span></p>
</div>
```

Este es el resultado que tengo.

```
    <div class="span10" style="text-align:justify; margin-left: 90px;" id="texto0">
<p class="NormalText" style="text-align:justify"></p>
<p class="NormalText" style="text-align:justify">
    <span style="font-size:18.0pt">&nbsp;</span></p>
<p class="NormalText" style="text-align:justify"></p>
<p class="NormalText" style="text-align:justify"></p>
<p class="NormalText" style="text-align:justify">
    <span style="font-size:18.0pt">&nbsp;</span></p>
</div>
```

El comportamiento que quiero lograr, es que a medida que valla leyendo el texto, se valla colocando de color rojo. Lo estoy haciendo en segmentos de 5.

Comment: Sería bueno que pusieras algo de contexto para entender el html y los contenidos de cada contenedor. También nos podrías mostrar qué está ocurriendo ahora y cómo querrías que quedase.

Comment: Comente que encontré una solución, a una parte de mi problema solo que ahora me doy cuenta que no estoy segmentado bien el array que creo para ir sombreando en rojo.

Comment: @YoelRodriguez, cuando tengas la solución, eres bienvenido de [responder a tu propia pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) y [aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí le dejo la solución que encontré:

```
    //Función para leer y ir borrado los texto del párrafo.
function panime (i = 0){

        $(ps[i]).text(function(){
            if(val != ''){
                a_str = $(this).text().trim().split(" ");
                len = a_str.length;
                var v = '';
                if(len > 5){
                    v = len / 5;
                    v = Math.round(v);
                }else{
                    v = 1;
                }
                search = '';
                ini = 0;
                fin = 5;
                //Conformamos la cadena a trabajar.
                for(c = 0; c <= v; c++){
                    a_seg = '';
                    a_seg = a_str.slice(ini,fin);
                    if(a_seg != ''){
                        hidden_text(a_seg,ps[i]);
                        search = '';
                        ini = ini + 5;
                        fin = fin + 5;                      
                    }
                }
                panime(i + 1);              
            }               
        });
}
```

Función para el proceso de sombrear en rojo ***hidden_text***:

```
    function hidden_text(a_seg,tp,callback) {

        for(i = 0; i < a_seg.length ; i++){
            search += a_seg[i]+" ";
        }

        search = search.replace(/&nbsp;/g,"").trim();
        var regex = new RegExp(search,'g');
        $(tp).html($(tp).text().replace(regex,'<span style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 18px;">'+search+'</span>'));

    if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Recuerda marcar como aceptada tu solucion. un saludo